# Why has Blender started not responding with every brush stroke I make

Tags: workflow

I have just recently started using Blender for 3d sculpting.

In the first week all proceeded well and I was learning quite a lot.

However this week as my sculpt started growing in size Blender began to be less and less responsive to the point that it is now not responding for quite some time with every brush stroke I make. This is making my work progress impossible.

1. First thought was that my file was too large in size: 700MB.
2. I managed to resample all the meshes of the object in my sculpt and file size was reduced to 80MB.
3. After resizing to 80MB Blender is still not responding.

Here is a breakdown of my PC system.

- Intel Core i7 4790 CPU 3.60GHz
- 32GB Ram
- 64 bit operating system
- Windows 10
- 4GB EVGA NVIDIA GeForce GTX1650 XC GDDR5 896 Core 1485MHz (1665MHz) Graphic Card

If I cannot solve this problem I will have to stop using Blender and I do not want to do so. If there's anybody that can help me solve this problem or at least address me to someone who can help me solve it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: As always: In this case, consider [uploading your blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so that someone can have a closer look at it.

Comment: what is a good way to upload here an 86MB file?   I have no problem showing it.  Thanks.

Comment: When saving your file, make sure you tick *Compress* – this will reduce the file size remarkably. After that, just use the link I provided in my last comment. This service is used often here.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6696" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6696/)  I had to take the head from this project to be able to upload it.  Basically it is a statue lying on a slab and I was about to start the body when the not responding error started to happen.

Comment: I don't know how to upload a picture or else I would upload a screen shoot of the project in full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the Subdivision Modifier on your main body. Your vertex count is high enough for smooth sculpting.